# Which script would append a new line to a table in "MS Word" 2003?

Tags: vbscript, ms-word, newline, windows-xp

I have this simple table in MSWord 2003:

[image]

I want to append one more line to this table:

```
turtle  dog rooster maple
```

Which VBScript commands (or set of commands) would I need here to do it automatically?

(I am using "Windows XP")

Comment: Do you mean VBScript that runs outside of Word or VBA that runs inside of Word?

Comment: @Remou: I mean VBScript that, of course, runs outside of the Word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some notes.

```
Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")

wd.Visible = True

Set doc = wd.Documents.Open ("c:\docs\addtotable.doc")

Set r = doc.Tables(1).Rows.Add

aa = Split("turtle,dog,rooster,maple", ",")

For i = 0 To r.Cells.Count - 1
  r.Cells(i + 1).Range.Text = aa(i)
Next
```

Comment: WOW!!! Remou, thank you! It works fine and does exactly what I wanted it to do. Just a small follow-up question: Is it possible to do the same thing without opening the "Word" document?

Comment: If you want, you can answer this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057998/how-to-make-this-vbs-script-keep-the-document-closed