# How to make this VBS script keep the document closed?

Tags: vbscript, windows-xp, ms-word, document

I just received this VBS code that appends a line to my table in MS "Word" 2003. It works fine, but I want it to add a line to the table without opening the file. Is it possible ? Or, perhaps, I need to use some command that would close the document as soon as it is opened.

```
Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")

wd.Visible = True

Set doc = wd.Documents.Open ("c:\docs\addtotable.doc")

Set r = doc.Tables(1).Rows.Add

aa = Split("turtle,dog,rooster,maple", ",")

For i = 0 To r.Cells.Count - 1
  r.Cells(i + 1).Range.Text = aa(i)
Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to open Word's window, use "wd.Visible = False" instead of "wd.Visible = True". In that case you may want to save to changed document to the same/a new file. Read the VBA documentation about .Save and .SaveAs. Closing the application by .Quit may be a good idea too.

Comment: "Read the VBA documentation about .Save and .SaveAs" - Why are you referring me to VBA instead of VBS? Are their commands absolutely identical?

Comment: You use VBScript (e.g. CreateObject) to get an object (e.g. a Word.Application). What you can do with/to that object is determined by that object (and documented in the Docs for that object). So the VBA Docs are the place to look for info about using Word (via automation by VBScript(s)).

Comment: @brilliant Be careful to catch errors if you set visible to false, or you could end up with half a dozen word applications in task manager before you know it, and then everything will fall apart :)

Comment: Thanks for this warning, Remou. Do you think I could do it away by simply adding  .Save or .SaveAs command to your script (at the moment I don't know how to do it) and then setting visible to false?